# importing xml with repeating fields import into ms access

Tags: xml, ms-access, import

I have some xmls for a game that I want to create a database for so that I can easily add more characters to the game. I found out how to import the xmls into access with no problem. But the problem comes when importing the xmls with the characters skills.

Each character can have several skills and they are all under the same tag. 
My problem comes here because when I import them into access it will only import the first skill and the others seem to be ignored. I find that I can import the data to excel but it creates multiple lines in order to deal with the various skills.

I want don't want to have to deal with a super long excel document when an access database would work better for me. Is there a good way to import xmls with repeating fields in them into an access file?

The problem that I am having is not just that it will separate the tables. That I can deal with. It will not add all of the skills which any given character can have. I will give an example of a character xml so you can more clearly see what I am talking about. 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9jb99sHVyQaNkM3bEQzcWhjNlE
This character has the skills Guard, Bouncer, Free Staff, Desert warrior, and jawbreaker. But if I try to import the xml into access, it will only show the bouncer skill as it is first in the list on the xml.

Comment: If it would be useful I can upload an example xml template

Comment: Honestly I haven't really known what to try

Comment: I have tried importing it directly. But it just imports the first skill in the list

Comment: I have tried importing it into excel but there it creates several lines and duplicates all the other data which only has one data entry per tag. I tried allowing duplicates under indexing, but that applies to the entries in the group and it didn't allow me to use the same header. I also saw info on using an sml to transform the data and I think that could work. I could just add an extra character to the end of it so it would become ,Skill1,,/Skill1, with the proper formatting of course. But I would have no idea how to even start on creating one of those or the code involved in changing that.

Comment: Sorry I meant using an xsl not sml.

Comment: *"If it would be useful I can upload an example xml template"* - Yes, a small representative sample of the XML would be helpful, particularly if it contains a parent-child relationship between a character and their skills.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9jb99sHVyQaMk13NVlRQndxSWM

Comment: This is a link to an xml template that I have for the game. The only part that I have had trouble with is the skills part. All the others have a single cell for their value. And most just have numerical input. At the moment I don't have any characters which require the alt_skills but I believe the plan is to add one soon.